# How to detect if an array of objects has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three array of objects, values and length of which can be changed by other components. I'm making an api call inside useEffect in a separate component. The api should only be called if any property inside any of the objects in the arrays changes value, or new objects are added or removed from the array. A lot of the stuff about these arrays can change so what's probably required is deep comparison.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const setPatientData = async () => {
        const filteredPatients = await services.patientsList('', pid);
    }
    setPatientData();
}, [ selectedFilters, selectedFiltersCheckbox, dropdownFilterKey ])

//What the arrays looks like (New Objects can be added to this)
const selectedFilters = [
  {
    key: "stratus" //this can change
    queried: false //this can change as well
  }
]
```

Comment: I would recommend not to mutate the array but instead create a new copy of the array. If you do that, you can check if something changes by object reference of the outer array.

Comment: `useEffect` is supposed to be tracking the changes to the objects specified in the array passed as its second argument. If changes are not showing up, it's because there's a violation of the immutability of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch the changes of an objects try [proxying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) the object or using a getter and setter with [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

One of react's core functionality is the State hook and Effect hook, which was built for exactly this purpose. So you'd do this.

In ParentComponent:

```
const [patientData, setPatientData] = useState({});
var temp_patient_data = apiCall(params);

setPatientData(temp_patient_data);
```

And then in ChildComponent:

```
var editable_patient_data = {...patient_data};
editable_patient_data['systolic_blood_pressure'] = 110

var props.setPatientData(editable_patient_data);
```

Then again in the ParentComponent:

```
useEffect(apiCall(axios.post(URL, patientData)), [patientData]);
```

**Explanation:**

React takes care of things like this using the State and Effect hook. State hooks store data throughout the lifecycle of the component. Effect hook listens for change on the state and executes a function when change is made.

You **SHOULD NOT** change the state variable directly without using the setState method, OR have an Effect hook listen for changes on anything that is not a state variable.